# Can I customize Carousel-indicators in react-responsive-carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, next.js, react-responsive-carousel

I am using the [react-responsive-carousel](http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/) library. Here, I want to change the default indicators CSS, dots shape to line shape.
My code is,

```
 <CarouselWrapper
      sx={{ marginTop: "124px", maxHeight: "486px", minHeight: "150px" }}
    >
      <Carousel autoPlay infiniteLoop showArrows={false}>
        <div>
          <Image src={image1} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image src={image1} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Image src={image1} />
        </div>
      </Carousel>
    </CarouselWrapper>
```

the current shape of those indicators,

[image]

Is it possible to customize that dots shape indicators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution if using SCSS and needing less customisation. Using a wrapping selector you can use:

```
  .yourSelector {
    :global(.carousel .control-dots .dot) {
            background-color: blue;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can customize the dots with a JSX passing `renderIndicator` prop as a function to `Carousel` component. You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-responsive-carousel) for a live working example of this usage.

```
<Carousel
      autoPlay
      infiniteLoop
      showArrows={false}
      renderIndicator={(onClickHandler, isSelected, index, label) => {
        const defStyle = { marginLeft: 20, color: "white", cursor: "pointer" };
        const style = isSelected
          ? { ...defStyle, color: "red" }
          : { ...defStyle };
        return (
          <span
            style={style}
            onClick={onClickHandler}
            onKeyDown={onClickHandler}
            value={index}
            key={index}
            role="button"
            tabIndex={0}
            aria-label={`${label} ${index + 1}`}
          >
            {"cust " + index}
          </span>
        );
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <img src={"1.jpeg"} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={"2.jpeg"} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={"3.jpeg"} />
      </div>
    </Carousel>
);
```

Comment: ticked it. can I get connected with you for learning from you? I am also a reactjs enthusiasts

Comment: how to change the dots shape to line shape instead of using texts?

Comment: You're welcome, I will update the sandbox accordingly.

Comment: You can do it only by customizing `.dot` css like in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dot-to-line-9edrw?file=/src/CustomIndicator.css).

Comment: Is there any way to control the number of cards/images shown? I want to show three cards at a time on the screen.

Comment: Although I'm able to do so by adding three card components in each div and then sliding that divs as you're moving the images. But I wonder if there is a way to control the number of elements shown in one time.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! Works well with replacing the custom text with icons like those from mui

Comment: would it be possible to only fill the indicators with a specific color?